# Append Data from a Data Frame to Google Sheet - Understanding the error -

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

The goal of this question is understand Why I get this error message if I do X and Why
I don't get if I do Y.

Probably is a silly question.

I want to update an Google Sheet from my End User Account on Google Colab.
The update consist in adding the column header of a data frame to a new worksheet.

I read the `gspread` [documentation](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/user-guide.html#using-gspread-with-pandas) and I saw how the do:

```
import pandas as pd

worksheet.update([dataframe.columns.values.tolist()] + dataframe.values.tolist())
```

Why if I remove the square brackets I get and error like:

> APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid value at 'data.values[0]' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue)

I created a reproducible code to try understand better:

```
# Creating my dummy Data Frame
test_dict = {"Date":[],"KPI1":[],"KPI2":[]}
test_df = pd.DataFrame(test_dict)

# Creating my test sheet on Google Sheet 
sheet_name_test= "Test"
sh_test = gc.create(sheet_name_test)

#Adding a specific worksheet
worksheet_test = sh_test.add_worksheet(title = "test", 
                               rows =10, 
                               cols =5)
#In that way works 
worksheet_test.update([test_df.columns.values.tolist()])
#In that way desn't work
worksheet_test.update(df_columns_order.columns.values.tolist())
```

In that way I get the previous highlighted error:

```
APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid value at \'data.values[0]\' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "Date"\nInvalid value at \'data.values[1]\' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "KPI1"\nInvalid value at \'data.values[2]\' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "KPI2"', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT', 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'data.values[0]', 'description': 'Invalid value at \'data.values[0]\' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "Date"'}, {'field': 'data.values[1]', 'description': 'Invalid value at \'data.values[1]\' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "KPI1"'}, {'field': 'data.values[2]', 'description': 'Invalid value at \'data.values[2]\' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue), "KPI2"'}]}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your showing script, I think that `test_df.columns.values.tolist()` is 1 dimensional array. When I saw the document of gsperad, it seems that `worksheet.update([42, 43, 44])` can be used. [Ref](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.4.0/api/models/worksheet.html?highlight=update#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.update)

But, when I saw the script of gspread, `update` method of Class Worksheet, the [Ref](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/gspread/worksheet.py#L769) It seems that the inputted values are directly used to the request body. [Ref](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/gspread/worksheet.py#L847) At "Method: spreadsheets.values.update" of Sheets API, it is required to use a 2-dimensional array to the values. I thought that this is the reason for your issue. (I'm not sure whether this is the current specification or a bug.)

In this situation, when you use the following script, no error occurs.

```py
worksheet_test.update([test_df.columns.values.tolist()])
```

When you use the following script, an error occurs in your showing error.

```py
worksheet_test.update(test_df.columns.values.tolist())
```

#### Note:

- This is for the current latest version (v5.4.0). This specification might be changed in the future update. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [update(range_name, values=None, **kwargs) of Class Worksheet](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.4.0/api/models/worksheet.html?highlight=update#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.update)
- [update(range_name, values=None, **kwargs) at GitHub](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/gspread/worksheet.py#L769)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)